# return id of newly created document in DocumentDB within .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, document-database

I am using the following to create a DocumentDB document, how can I ament it to return the guid id of the document that gets created?

```
            _logger.LogInformation("creating document");
            Uri uri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DatabaseId, CollectionId);
            await client.CreateDocumentAsync(uri, doc);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply read id value from the document after saving it:

```
 await client.CreateDocumentAsync(uri, doc);
 _logger.LogInformation($"created document {doc.Id}");
```